# How can I manage users using Parse .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, parse-platform, parse-dotnet-sdk

How can I update and delete users using Parse .NET SDK

its mentioned in SDK guide that this possible using Master API Key but there is no details how to do that 
is this possible to do this directly in .NET SDK or we  must create cloud function to do that and call it from SDK

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know the parse .NET SDK but I use parse in my android projects directly from rest API, in the rest API we have methods to update and delete users as you can see here

https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#users

You can use the restsharp lib to help you :D

http://restsharp.org/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks Milton for you answer I know that this possible using Rest API but i ask if this possible using .NET SDK